# How to create a local directory using Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am pretty new with electron.
Can anyone suggest me how to create a local folder using the electron. I see JavaScript does not have that capability.

Comment: Do you mean for application cache, or a place where the user will save data? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: where user can save data.

Answer (score 18):

The file system module ([fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)) is also available in electron. You can use [`mkdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback) to create a directory:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

// Without checking if dir already exists
fs.mkdir('PATH/TO/DIR');

// With checking if dir already exists
if (!fs.existsSync('PATH/TO/DIR')) fs.mkdir('PATH/TO/DIR');
```

Comment: I tried this but I get 'permission denied' after packaging the app

Comment: Thats something you need to take care of on OS level

Comment: How do I do that? How do I get permissions for my app to create a directory or a file?

Comment: I had the same trouble. I did 1 things: 1) used absolute paths; 2) in electron 1.6.2 I used one more "../" - and this worked for me

Comment: one more "../" where?

Comment: the default application path for apps built with electron-builder is a read-only archive, not a folder.  using __dirname + '/../' prefix will locate the parent folder, which is a normal windows folder.  However you still may have permission issues.  try app.getPath('userData') to get the path to a writable folder.

Comment: Also consider doing a check before to make sure it doesn't exist already with `if (!fs.existsSync('PATH/TO/DIR')) fs.mkdir('PATH/TO/DIR');`

Comment: @YanFoto Nice one!